# questions regarding the order statistics of a normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Assume $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are realizations from a normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$ and assume they are ordered from small to large. Let $y_i=x_i-x_{i-1}$ be the difference of the two adjacent numbers (so $y_i$ is always larger than $0$). My questions are:

1) What is the distribution of $y_i$? and

2) How can I test if $y_i$ is statistically different from $0$?

Comment: @EricPeterson, that's not what the question is. they pre-order number before subtracting

Comment: 2) $P[y_i=0]=0$, you may need to reformulate your 2nd question. perhaps, in intervals or maybe in discrete distributions.

Comment: Since $y_i$ is, as you say, *always larger than 0*, what is the value in testing something you know for certain? What's the underlying point? Is this for some subject?

Answer (score 1):

Using results from **H.A. David & H.N. Nagaraja (2003), "Order Statistics" (3d edition) ch. 2**:

The probability density function of $Y_i \equiv X_{(i)}-X_{(i-1)}$ where the $X$'s are order statistics from a sample of size $n$ of i.i.d random variables having probability density function $f_X(x)$ and cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$, is:

$$f_Y(y_i) = \frac {n!}{(i-2)!(n-i)!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [F_X(t)]^{i-2}[1-F_X(t+y_i]^{n-i}f_X(t)f_X(t+y_i)dt$$